# Error en interfaz de angular TS2322 y firestore

Tags: angular, ionic, users-roles, interfaz

Estoy tratando de que mi interfaz, en Angular 12, tenga mas parametros, para que estos sean extraidos de firestore, actualmente, y funcional, está lo siguiente(Es el archivo completo)

```
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  displayName: string;
  emailVerified: boolean;
}
```

Y como lo invoco desde mi .ts es

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { User } from "./../shared/User";
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
user$: Observable<User> = this.authSvc.afAuth.user;
constructor(private authSvc: AuthService){}
    this.user$.forEach(user => {
      console.log('rol', user.uid);//Imprime el ID que firestore le asignó
    });
```

Si trato de agregar el campo `role: string;` me tira errores en todos mis .ts que usan este usuario, dando el error

---

`error TS2322: Type 'import(".../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<firebase.User>' is not assignable to type 'import(".../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<import("S:/Trabajo/Coincaex/src/app/shared/User").User>'`

---

Y buscando en internet, me topé con esta supuesta solución `[role: string]: any;` pero cuando lo trato de imprimir, me sale `undefine`. Que puedo estar haciendo mal en la interfaz??

Answer (score 0):

El error te lo dice. Tienes definida una interfase o clase de tipo `firebase.User` y otra que se llama igual, pero ubicada en `shared/User`. Para que tu modificación funcione ambas deben ser iguales o ,en caso de que sea posible, usar la misma interfaz en ambas parte.